# Paypal shopping cart AMOUNT_ERROR

Tags: paypal, cart, shopping-cart

I am having a issue with a paypal cart since the update around march (bit late but the site is not used yet and we just discovered it now).

I already checked this question but it did not solve the issue for a shopping cart ([Paypal : hosted button payments fail with code=AMOUNT_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637900/paypal-hosted-button-payments-fail-with-code-amount-error))

We send a object that contains the request data through a plugin called neo.js, this works fine as far as we know.
This is our data we send to paypal as a js object.

```
{
    amount_1:        10.01,
    business:        "noreply@domain.com",
    cancel_return:   "https://dev.domain.com",
    charset:         "utf-8",
    cmd:             "_cart",
    currency_code:   "US",
    custom:          "username",
    item_name_1:     "$10 item",
    item_number_1:   "1",
    no_shipping:     1,
    notify_url:      "https://dev.domain.com/callback/paypal.php",
    quantity_1:      1,
    return:          "https://dev.domain.com",
    upload:          1
}
```

It has to do something with the amount, but using a , instead of . but that only gives a normal error message on screen that the format is incorrect.
We have tried multiple things including the dollar sign and making it a string but nothing seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the error and it is due to the wrong currency code passed.

You are passing "US" but the currency code (that is a parameter that refers to the AMOUNT as in the error returned) must be of 3 characters as you can see on PayPal guide: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/

Change it to "USD" instead and you will have a working checkout.